# Normal subgroup.

Tags: normal-subgroups

Let $N$ be subgroup of a group $G$. Suppose that, for each $a\in G$, there exists $b\in G$ such that $Na=bN$. 
Prove that $N$ is a normal subgroup.

Please guide me with a proof. Thank you for your kindness.

This is Exercise, Hungerford.

Comment: $a \in bN$ hence $bN =aN$

Comment: It has been very helpful!!~~

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show that for any $a$, $aN =Na$. Since there is a $b $ such that $aN =Nb$,and $a\in aN =Nb$, it follows that $a\in Nb$. Thus $Nb=Na$.

Comment: Thack you vert much. It has been very helpful.!!